# Reporting Services E-Mail Subscription Is Always in Pending Status

Tags: email, reporting-services, reporting

We have many e-mail subscriptions on your report server; but e-mail subscription status's are always "Pending" more than 4 days. Newly configured subscriptions are pending also. Status is not changing and there is no exception or error or warning on report server logs. Is there anybody with any ideas? How can I trace subscription logs with more details?

P.S. E-mails send with relay on our exchange server and our system team said that they couldn't trace e-mails with sending relay.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was faced with the same problem? How your case was solved (if was)?

Answer (score 0):

Read this, particularly the part about changing SMTPAuthenticate to 2 - that's what worked for me:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx

For continued troubleshooting if that doesn't solve your problem:

- If you're using email aliases, try switching to fully declared email addresses (e.g., change "Bob Smith" to "Bob.Smith@YourCompany.com")
- Each subscription should have a corresponding SQL Agent job for it; read the logs on those job(s) (see here for matching a job to a subscription, if you aren't aware: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1846)
- Check the SSRS logfiles (...\ReportingServices\LogFiles)
- Check the SSRS tables - ActiveSubscriptions, RunningJobs, Subscriptions - likely won't find the problem there, but these tables may aid in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner of the subscription in SSRS (it may be a user which is no longer valid).