# SSRS - how do I stop a report with a pending status

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have almost 100 SSRS reports that run overnight. One of them has had a status of Pending since Friday night and it is now Monday. How can I reset the report so that it will run tonight?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a subscription rather than a report?  If so have looked at these http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/andy_warren/2015/07/01/reporting-services-subscriptions-in-pending-status/ or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854526/reporting-services-e-mail-subscription-is-always-in-pending-status ?

Answer (score 0):

This does relate to a subscription rather than report.
I did not find a reason for the pending status. I went through the subscription wizard to the finish. It did not change the status but the report ran correctly on that evening.